# Is commit/rollback like operation available in Rest API?

Tags: rest-api

I want to do the followings in a row but it seems that composite request cannot do that. Is there a Rest API feature like commit/rollback in database?

1. Insert record to table A and receive record's ID
2. Insert another record which is associated with the ID to table B

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to provide additional detail. As it stands it doesn't explain well what you are trying to do, what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: If you want to do composite inserts consider using [external IDs in your upsert](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.inserting_updating_or_deleting_data.htm&type=5) for the relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no commit/rollback in the REST API

...but you shouldn't need that here. The composite resource allows you to create a simple reference which can be used in subsequent requests (within the composite call).

From [Send Multiple Requests Using Composite](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_composite_post.htm) (part of the REST API documentation). Emphasis mine.

> Executes a series of REST API requests in a single call. **You can use the output of one request as the input to a subsequent request**. The response bodies and HTTP statuses of the requests are returned in a single response body. The entire series of requests counts as a single call toward your API limits.
> The requests in a composite call are called subrequests. All subrequests are executed in the context of the same user. **In a subrequest’s body, you specify a reference ID that maps to the subrequest’s response. You can then refer to the ID in the url or body fields of later subrequests by using a JavaScript-like reference notation.**
>
> For example, the following composite request body includes two subrequests. The first creates an account and designates the output as refAccount. The second creates a contact parented under the new account by referencing refAccount in the subrequest body.
>
> ```
> {
> "compositeRequest" : [{
>   "method" : "POST",
>   "url" : "/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/Account",
>   "referenceId" : "refAccount",
>   "body" : { "Name" : "Sample Account" }
>   },{
>   "method" : "POST",
>   "url" : "/services/data/v56.0/sobjects/Contact",
>   "referenceId" : "refContact",
>   "body" : { 
>     "LastName" : "Sample Contact",
>     "AccountId" : "@{refAccount.id}"
>     }
>   }]
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are mistaken composite API's can do the above operation
2. You don't need to pass recordId
3. Use the child relationship name for eg Account and contact
4. We first create an account and then using the child relationship name Contacts we will create contacts related to that newly created account
5. "attributes" : {"type" : "Account", "referenceId" : "ref1"},

   "name" : "SampleAccount1",
   "phone" : "1234567890",
   "website" : "www.salesforce.com",
   "numberOfEmployees" : "100",
   "industry" : "Banking",
   "Contacts" : {
   "records" : [{
   "attributes" : {"type" : "Contact", "referenceId" : "ref2"},
   "lastname" : "Smith",
   "Title" : "President",
   "email" : "sample@salesforce.com"
   },{
   "attributes" : {"type" : "Contact", "referenceId" : "ref3"},
   "lastname" : "Evans",
   "title" : "Vice President",
   "email" : "sample@salesforce.com"
   }]
   }
   }